# Joda Time sum various times

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm using joda time 2.7 , I need to add several times in LocalTime format , ignoring TimeZone and toDateTimeToday ;

example:

input (String ... times)

```
01:10 , 01:10 , 01:10 ,
```

or

```
01:10 , 01:10 , 01:10 , 01:10 , 01:10 , 01:10
```

expected output in ( Millis )

```
03:30
```

or
expected output in ( Millis )

```
07:00
```

**My ideia**

```java
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.Duration;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

static long sumAccumulatedTimes( long... listTimes ){

    Duration duration = Duration.ZERO;
    DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.getDefault();
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
    for (int i = 0; i < listTimes.length; i++) { 
       duration = duration.plus( listTimes[i] ); // in iteration three, ocurred problems!
    } 
    long convertZone = zone.convertUTCToLocal( duration.getMillis() ); // Adjust TimeZone
    System.out.println("Output: " + fmt.print( convertZone  ) );
    return 0; // ignore !
 }




// Call method

  DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm"); 
  sumAccumulatedTimes(  
       fmt.parseMillis("01:10"),
       fmt.parseMillis("01:10")//, up to here Ok (02:20 ouput), next inconsitent values 
      // fmt.parseMillis("01:10") // add three parameters, is ocurred problems
    );
```

**EDIT: Update**

**Solved by** @Meno Hochschild

```java
String[] input = { "12:00", "12:10" };
PeriodFormatter parser =
new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
.appendHours().appendLiteral(":")
.appendMinutes().toFormatter();
Period period = Period.ZERO;

for (String s : input) {
  period = period.plus(parser.parsePeriod(s));
 }

 PeriodFormatter printer =
  new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
  .printZeroAlways().minimumPrintedDigits(2)
 //.appendDays().appendLiteral(":") // remove original code
 .appendHours().appendLiteral(":")
 .appendMinutes().toFormatter();
 //System.out.println("duration=" +  // remove original code    //printer.print(period.normalizedStandard()));
// output: duration=01:00:10

 System.out.println("duration="                                        
  printer.print(period.normalizedStandard( PeriodType.time() )));
// output: duration= 24:10
```

**Other Soluction**, by @Dexter   :)

```java
private static String sumAccumulatedTimes( String... times ){

    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
    DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.getDefault();
    PeriodFormatter pformat = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
                                    .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
                                    .printZeroAlways()
                                    .appendHours()
                                    .appendLiteral(":")
                                    .appendMinutes()
                                    .toFormatter();

    long sum = 0;  
    for ( String time : times ) { 
        long parseLong = fmt.parseMillis( time );
        sum += zone.convertUTCToLocal( parseLong ); 
    } 
    Period period = new Period( sum );  
    return period.toString(pformat);
}
```

Times the sum two solutions work , ignoring time zone without limitation 24 hours

Thank you.

Comment: Adding times doesn't make sense since time has no starting point. Do you want to add durations instead?

Comment: ... what? In english, please?

Comment: @specializt , I'm Sorry ,  my english is not good,     what problems ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `DateTimeFormatter` to parse durations. That formatter is designed for formatting and parsing points in time and cannot process any time overflow and also tries to mangle any calculated durations **with timezone issues** (the root cause of your problem). In my timezone "Europe/Berlin", the expression `fmt.parseMillis("01:10")` yields 10 minutes only - not one hour and ten minutes.

Use a duration formatter instead. In Joda-Time, this is called `PeriodFormatter`:

```
String[] input = { "01:10", "01:10", "01:10", "01:10", "01:10", "01:10" };
PeriodFormatter pf =
  new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
  .minimumPrintedDigits(2).printZeroAlways()
  .appendHours().appendLiteral(":").appendMinutes().toFormatter();
Period period = Period.ZERO;

for (String s : input) {
  period = period.plus(pf.parsePeriod(s));
}

System.out.println("duration=" + pf.print(period.normalizedStandard()));
// output: duration=07:00
```

**Updated after comment of OP (fix for mishandling day overflow):**

```
String[] input = { "12:00", "12:10" };
PeriodFormatter parser =
  new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
  .appendHours().appendLiteral(":")
  .appendMinutes().toFormatter();
Period period = Period.ZERO;

for (String s : input) {
  period = period.plus(parser.parsePeriod(s));
}

PeriodFormatter printer =
  new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
  .printZeroAlways().minimumPrintedDigits(2)
  .appendDays().appendLiteral(":")
  .appendHours().appendLiteral(":")
  .appendMinutes().toFormatter();
System.out.println("duration=" + printer.print(period.normalizedStandard()));
// output: duration=01:00:10
```

An alternative fix is using the expression `period.normalizedStandard(PeriodType.time())` in order to use clock units only.

Comment: Trank's __ Meno

I am aware of the use of DateTimeFormatter , I only use to convert .
My problem was the incorrect result due to time zone.
I tried using Period but had no result.
In your response Period, see the difference that makes it work.

period = period.plus ( pf.parsePeriod (s ) ) ;

and also

period.normalizedStandard ()

I did not use these functions .


His response to me worked.

Comment: I found a problem using the addition there is a limitation period of 24 hours and this causes problems .

ex:
input sum 12:00 and 12:10 expected result equal to 24:10 period result using the result is 00:10

Comment: Excellent !
making the changes your code works without limitation of 24 hours, thank you !
I added your solution!!

Answer (score 0):

You can just add millisecond.

```
   static long sumAccumulatedTimes(String ... array)
   {
      long sum = 0;
      for (String time : array)
      {
         sum += new LocalTime(time).getMillisOfDay();
      }
      return sum;
   }
```

The result will be the same

**UPD**
Convert long to string witout Joda API

```
   static String millisToString(long millis)
   {
      long hours = millis / (1000 * 60 * 60);
      long minutes = (millis / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
      return hours + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
   }
```

Comment: @llya ,  when using Localtime in a sum he reapplies the time zone , I find problem.
My time zone is GMT + 03
eg
entry 12:00 and 12:10 using your code get the output 21:10

Comment: @Dexter No. Output of this code is `long` and is `87000000` = 24 hours + 10 minutes. So the problem is in converting `long` to `string`

Comment: @Dexter I have added method that converts `long` to `string`. This solution is shorter and takes less resources

Comment: @llya , add comment  in Answer.

Answer (score 0):

@llya.

Now your code solves the issue !
But in my case it generates me 
incompatibility issues using this long 
in other methods JODA .

e.g.

```
                                     //87600000
  static String parseMillisToTextTime( long time ){ 
      DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm"); 
      return fmt.print(time); 
  } // ouput 21:20


    System.out.println(  LocalTime.fromMillisOfDay(87600000).toString("HH:mm") );
  // output 00:20


   LocalTime lt = new LocalTime(87600000);
  System.out.println("output: " + lt.toString("HH:mm"));
  // output 21:20
```

For me to change this method 
have a high burden of maintenance.

If you want to add your 
solution with these observations?